# I want to insert a user defined integer in mysql database

Tags: android

For example :

```
Button insertData;
Int a=5;
```

I want insert this number 5 in Mysql database when I click on `Button`  `insertData`.

Comment: Try to use Sugar ORM 
http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

Comment: Please define `user defined integer`. An integer is an integer. It's not a user defined type.

Answer (score 0):

Create an end point to insert the data into database and use a library (Volley, retrofit or apache http) to make a call to the server with the params and get the response and show it to users.

Comment: Sir I didnt get you. can you tell me bye example?

Comment: compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial/   check this link